# Securing a simple image proxy service

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

My MEAN stack application shows images from various sources. As the app is delivered over https I created a simple proxy server to serve up the images to avoid "mixed content" warnings.

The route accepts an encoded url of the image to fetch:

```
  router.get('/images/:url',function(req, res) {
    var url = decodeURIComponent(req.params.url);
    request.get(url).pipe(res);
  });
```

However, I don't want this to be abused. I only want my application to be able to make use of this feature. How should I go about adding this layer of security?

Comment: is it open for all or only registered users can access this?

Comment: Any user can access it

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to HTTP access control (CORS) headers.

> A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain than the one which the first resource itself serves. For example, an HTML page served from http://domain-a.com makes an  src request for http://domain-b.com/image.jpg. Many pages on the web today load resources like CSS stylesheets, images and scripts from separate domains.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header:

A returned resource may have one Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, with the following syntax:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin> | *
```

The origin parameter specifies a URI that may access the resource.  The browser must enforce this.  For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource.

For example, to allow http://mozilla.com to access the resource, you can specify:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mozilla.com
```

For more info see [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: This wouldn't stop server based requests